# Important differences for InfiniBand cables?

Tags: networking

I'm currently looking into an cheap InfiniBand solution and it seems like used 20 Gigabit/s host cards and switches are rather cheap to get but I'm getting really confused when it comes to cables as the prices are differing a lot and their tech description differs as well (if they even have any, many that I found just have a part number and the length).

I couldn't find any ressources that explain the diffrences (if there are any). I found cables that are supposed to connect to SAS/S-ATA which sounded very weird to me and it seems that there is some sort of quality difference.

So, what do I need to look for if I want a cable that would connect a host card and switch that support 20Gbit/s (both card and switch that I looked into a little closer have a "4x DDR" spec but I'm not exactly sure what that tells me, DDR as in DDR memory?).

Some clarity would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following two sections are direct quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand)

---

### Effective unidirectional theoretical throughput (actual data rate, not signaling rate)

```
         SDR       DDR       QDR     FDR-10           FDR        EDR
 1X  2 Gbit/s  4 Gbit/s  8 Gbit/s  10 Gbit/s  13.64 Gbit/s  25 Gbit/s
 4X  8 Gbit/s 16 Gbit/s 32 Gbit/s  40 Gbit/s  54.54 Gbit/s 100 Gbit/s
12X 24 Gbit/s 48 Gbit/s 96 Gbit/s 120 Gbit/s 163.64 Gbit/s 300 Gbit/s
```

### Physical Interconnection

InfiniBand uses copper CX4 cable for SDR and DDR rates — also commonly used to connect SAS (Serial Attached SCSI) HBAs to external (SAS) disk arrays. With SAS, this is known as an SFF-8470 connector, and is referred to as an "InfiniBand-style" Connector. The latest connectors used with QDR and FDR are QSFP (Quad SFP) and can be copper or fiber, depending on the length required.

---

So it seems SAS cable is acceptable in some situation.

Comment: Thanks, thats good to know. So CX4 is the cable type used for any cooper based Infiniband product and does not mean it uses 4 connections?

Comment: That may be in relation to SAS, which is essentially 4 SATA 3/6gbps connections in a single cable.

Comment: I see so as long as the connector fits I don't have any complication with using a cable that is certified as a SAS InfiniBand cable?